# Solution to Diff Eq Using Integrating Factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We were given the following series of equations:

```
X' = X + Y (1)
Y' = Y (2)
```

and we were told to find the general solution.

Here is what I did:

1. Integrated both sides of (2)
2. Substituted the resulting value of Y = 1/2Y^2 into (1).
3. Rewrote (1) as X' - 1/2Y^2 = X, which is now of the form dy/dx + (-Py) = Q
4. Now I plan to determine the integrating factor and go from there.

My question is: am I on the right path or is there something else I should be doing?  Thank you.

Comment: You did a mistake by assuming the derivative is taken with respect to Y, but Y is a function and not a variable.

Comment: @Moo, I tried using Eigenvalues/Eigenvectors, but there is only one eigenvalue/eigenvector and I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $y'(t)=y(t)$. We can write $y'$ as $\frac{dy}{dt}$. Putting the $y$ related things on the left and the $t$ related things on the right, we get:
$$\frac{1}{y(t)}dy=dt$$
Now integrating:
$$\int\frac{1}{y(t)}dy=\int dt$$
$$ln(y)=t+C$$
$$y(t)=e^{(t+C)}$$
$$y(t)=e^te^C$$
$e^C$ is just a constant, so we get that $e^t\cdot constant = ce^t$
Now that we know $y(t)=ce^t$, we plug it back in to the first equation to get
$$x'=x+ce^t$$
Moving the $x$ to the left, and multiplying by $e^{-t}$, we get
$$x'e^{-t}-xe^{-t}=ce^te^{-t}$$
The left side is just $(xe^{-t})'$ (which you can verify using product rule),  and the right side is just $c$. Integrating with respect to t, we get 
$$\int (xe^{-t})' dt = \int c dt$$
$$xe^{-t} = ct+d$$
Where $d$ is some other constant. Multiplying by $e^t$, we have
$$x(t)=cte^t+de^t$$